# Compare current week to previous week

Tags: sql-server

I have a list of members by week and I need to compare the current week to the previous in SQL Server.The first image is how the data is in table and the second image is what I want as a result. I thought maybe doing a CTE for each week and then comparing them. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add any data to your question as SQL DDL statements and not images, as this makes it much easier for us to help you rather than having to manually write out what is in the images

Comment: Also, how are you defining `new` members?  If a member is present in week 22, absent in week 23 and then back again in week 24 are they classes as new?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very naive approach that counts all `mem_id` values that weren't in the previous week as `new` could look like this:

```
declare @t table(mem_id int,weeknum int, yearnum int);
insert into @t values(1,1,2020),(2,1,2020),(1,2,2020),(3,2,2020),(2,3,2020),(3,3,2020),(4,3,2020);

with p as
(
    select yearnum
          ,weeknum
          ,case when lag(weeknum,1) over (partition by mem_id order by yearnum,weeknum) = weeknum-1 then 0 else 1 end as p
    from @t
)
select yearnum
      ,weeknum
      ,sum(p) as new
      ,count(1) as total
from p
group by yearnum
        ,weeknum
order by yearnum
        ,weeknum;
```

### Output

```
+---------+---------+-----+-------+
| yearnum | weeknum | new | total |
+---------+---------+-----+-------+
|    2020 |       1 |   2 |     2 |
|    2020 |       2 |   1 |     2 |
|    2020 |       3 |   2 |     3 |
+---------+---------+-----+-------+
```

Comment: That is it! Thank you! I've never used Lag before. What is the '1' in count(1) ?

Comment: It is just a dummy value so SQL Server doen't go and pull the value out of a column.  This can save a very small amount of processing in some situation but more importantly always counts a row regardless of the data within it.  If you were to run `count(colname)` over 10 rows, of which 2 `colname` values were `null`, the `count` returned would be 8 as `null` values are ignored.

Comment: Thanks again. Much appreciated.